# What's the inverse of an adjoint endomorphism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, representation-theory, commutator

$\def\ada{\text{ad}_A}$Suppose $A,B$ are operators in Quantum Mechanics, the [adjoint endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_algebra) $\text{ad}_A$ can be expressed by
$$
\text{ad}_A B=[A,B]=AB-BA
$$
and
$$\text{ad}_A^0B=B, \quad \ada^n B= [\underbrace{A,\cdots,[A}_{n\text{ times}},B]].\tag{1}$$

The BCH formula writes
$$
\mbox{e}^{-A}B\mbox{e}^{A} = \mbox{e}^{\ada}B
=\sum_{n=0}^1 \frac 1{n!} {\text{ad}_A^n}B,\tag{2}
$$
whose proof can be found in [wiki - BCH forumal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#:%7E:text=%5Bedit%5D-,The%20identity%20(Campbell%201897),-%5Bedit%5D) .

In a special case where
$$
[A,[A,B]]=[B,[B,A]]=0\quad \text{or}\quad \text{ad}_A^2B=\text{ad}_B^2A=0, \tag{3}
$$
[Glauber's formula](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/350267/289541)  holds,
$$
\mbox{e}^{A}\mbox{e}^B=\mbox{e}^{A+B+[A,B]/2}.\tag{4}
$$

These two proofs use the same trick. I'll repeat it for Eq.(4).

Let $C(\alpha)=\mbox{e}^{\alpha A}\mbox{e}^{\alpha B}$, take the derivative
$$
\frac{\mbox{d} C}{\mbox{d}\alpha}=AC+\mbox{e}^{\alpha A}B\mbox{e}^{-\alpha A} C= ({A+\mbox{e}^{\alpha\ada} B})C,\tag{5}
$$
where Eq.(1) and $\text{ad}_{\alpha A}=\alpha \text{ad}_A$ is used. When Eq(3) holds, Eq.(2) can be truncated as
$$
\frac{\mbox d C}{\mbox dt}=({A+B+\alpha [A,B]})C.\tag{6}
$$
Because $A,B$ are independent of $\alpha$, take the integral and setting $\alpha=1$ will finish the proof of eq. (4).

My question is: can the integral of Eq.(6) be taken if Eq.(3) does not hold? The difficulty is the integral of $\exp(\alpha\text{ad}_A)B$.  By analogy with the integral of usual function
$$
\int\mbox d x \exp({k x })=\frac 1k\exp({kx}),
$$
I need someing like $\text{ad}_A^{-1}$, the "inverse" of $\text{ad}_A$. Since $\text{ad}_A$ is the derivative of the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Adjoint_representation_of_a_Lie_algebra)
$$
\text{ad}_A =\mbox{d}(\text{Ad})_I (A),
$$
the inverse may be someting like an integral. What's the expression of it, and can it be expressed in the form of operator products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Concerning the title question (v3) about the inverse of the adjoint endomorphism $\text{ad}_A$, it is typically not invertible. Think of an abelian Lie algebra.
2. However, it seems OP's main question is to construct a proof of [Dynkin's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Dynkin%27s_formula). This can be found in e.g. Brian Hall's textbook *Lie Groups, Lie Algebras, and Representations.*