# What is the commutator of the exponential derivative operator and the exponential position operator?

Tags: operators, commutator

What is the commutator of the exponential derivative operator and the exponential position operator?
\begin{align}
\left[\exp(\partial_x),\exp(x)\right]
=\exp(\partial_x)\exp(x)
-\exp(x)\exp(\partial_x)=~?
\end{align}

I first wrote down the exponentials into there power series sum
\begin{align}
\left[\exp(\partial_x),\exp(x)\right]
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{\partial_x^n}{n!}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{\partial_x^m}{m!}
-
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{x^n}{n!}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{\partial_x^m}{m!},
\end{align}
and then grouped like terms
\begin{align}
\left[\exp(\partial_x),\exp(x)\right]
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{
\left[
\partial_x^n
x^m
-
x^n
\partial_x^m
\right]
}{n!m!},
\end{align}
and then evaluate the derivatives
\begin{align}
\left[\exp(\partial_x),\exp(x)\right]
=
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}
\dfrac{
\left[
\partial_x^n
(x^m)
+
x^m
\partial_x^n
-
x^n
\partial_x^m
\right]
}{n!m!}.
\end{align}
I am not sure if$$
\partial_x^n\left(x^m\right)~=~\frac{m!}{\left(m-n+1\right)!} \, x^{m-n}
\,,$$and then I got stuck.

Comment: Do you know how $[x,F(p)]$ behaves? Do you know how $[x^2, p]$ behaves? If the answer is yes to both, you should be able to do this question (though it certainly looks a bit lengthy in the math!); if not, then you may want to look into solving those two general cases first before taking a stab at this one.

Comment: Have you heard of the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suresh is right, the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) will save you. If $\left[A,B\right]$ commutes with $A$ and $B$ you have,

$$ \exp\left(A\right)\exp\left(B\right) = \exp\left(A+B+\frac{1}{2}\left[A,B\right]\right) \, .$$

Then the answer to your question is

$$ \exp\left(\partial_x\right)\exp\left(x\right) = 2 \exp\left(x+\partial_x\right) \sinh(1/2) \, .$$

Answer (score 3):

Besides the truncated BCH formula (which is also proven in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132886/2451) Phys.SE post and mentioned in Steven Mathey's answer), in practice one often wants to normal order the differential operators, i.e. putting all the $x$'s to the left of all the $\partial_x$. To this end the formula

$$\tag{1} e^{a\partial_x}f(x) ~=~ f(x+a)e^{a\partial_x}. $$

is useful. Hence the sought-for normal-ordered commutator becomes

$$\tag{2} [e^{a\partial_x}, e^{bx}] ~=~(e^{b(x+a)}-e^{bx})e^{a\partial_x}.$$

Comment: It is this form of the BCH formula that I had in mind though it can be derived from Steven Mathey's answer as well.