# Proof of weaker Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff Formula

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, lie-algebra, commutator

Prove the weaker form of the BCH Formula:

$$e^A e^B = e^{A + B + \frac{1}{2}[A,B]} $$

with the assumption $[A, [B, A]] = 0; [B, [B,A]] = 0$

Start with $f(\lambda) = e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B} e^{-\lambda (A + B)}$ and establish the differential equation $\frac{df}{d\lambda} = \lambda [A, B] f.$ Then integrate it to obtain the formula.

What I did is I worked backwards.It is very easy to see that 
$$ \frac{df}{d\lambda} = \lambda[A,B]f$$
$$ \frac{df}{f} = \lambda[A,B] d\lambda $$
$$ \log f = \frac{\lambda^2}{2}[A,B] $$
$$ f = e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B} e^{-\lambda (A + B)} = e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2}[A,B]} $$
$$ e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B} = e^{\lambda (A+B)} e^{\frac{\lambda^2}{2} [A,B]}$$
then take $\lambda = 1 $ to obtain

$$e^A e^B = e^{A + B + \frac{1}{2}[A,B]} $$

Now the hard part is obtaining the differential equation.
$$f(\lambda) = e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B} e^{-\lambda (A + B)}$$
$$ \frac{df}{d\lambda} = Ae^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B} e^{-\lambda (A+B)} + e^{\lambda A} Be^{\lambda B} e^{-\lambda (A+B)} - e^{\lambda A} e^{\lambda B} e^{-\lambda (A + B)} (A+B) $$

The best I could make from this mess was

$$ \frac{df}{d\lambda} = [A,f] + e^{\lambda A}e^{\lambda B} [B, e^{-\lambda (A+B)}] $$

It's really difficult for me to be able to use the assumptions $[A, [B, A]] = 0; [B, [B,A]] = 0$ nor make $\lambda$ come down the exponent in the differential equation.

Can you please give a hint on how to proceed with this problem? Any helpful hint will be extremely appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Posssible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/132886/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, I assume finite dimensional operators: otherwise you need to check certain boundedness conditions on the operators. Because the CBH series is here truncated by the vanishing double commutators, the conditions for linear operators on *e.g.* $\mathbf{L}^2(\mathbb{R})$ will be mild.

You need to practice operations with $\mathrm{Ad}$. Look up the following. In the Lie group $\mathfrak{G}$ with algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ the tangent vector to the path:

$$\sigma:\mathbb{R}\to\mathfrak{G};\;\sigma(\tau) = e^A\,e^{\tau\,B}\,e^{-A};\;A,\,B\in\mathfrak{g}\tag{1}$$

at the identity is $\mathrm{Ad}(e^A)\,B=\exp(\mathrm{ad}(A))\,B$. Here $\mathrm{Ad}:\mathfrak{G}\to GL(\mathfrak{g})$ is the [Adjoint Representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation). It is a Lie group homomorphism from the general Lie group $\mathfrak{G}$ to the matrix Lie group $GL(\mathfrak{g})$. Its kernel is the centre of $\mathfrak{G}$. Since it is a homomorphism, we have $\mathrm{Ad}(\gamma\,\zeta) = \mathrm{Ad}(\gamma)\,\mathrm{Ad}(\zeta);\,\forall \gamma,\,\zeta\in\mathfrak{G}$. Another useful identity is:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}\mathrm{Ad}(e^A)\,B &=& \exp(\mathrm{ad}(A))\,B \\&=&B + \mathrm{ad}(A) B + \frac{\mathrm{ad}(A)^2}{2!}\,B +\cdots \\&=& B+ [A,\,B] + \frac{1}{2!}\, [A,\,[A,\,B]] + \cdots\end{array}\tag{2}$$

and this series is *universally convergent* if the operator $B\mapsto[A,\,B]$ is suitably bounded (*e.g.* $\left\|[A,\,B]\right\| \leq K(A)\,\left\|B\right\|$ for some $K(A)\in\mathbb{R}$ - this is certainly true in finite dimensions).

Now, by (1) and the homomorphism property ($\mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,A}\,e^{\lambda\,B}) = \mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,A})\,\mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,B})$), you can find that:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}\mathrm{d}_\lambda f &=& A\,e^{\lambda\, A}\,e^{\lambda\,B}\,e^{-\lambda\,(A+B)} +  e^{\lambda\, A}\,B\,e^{\lambda\,B}\,e^{-\lambda\,(A+B)} - e^{\lambda\, A}\,e^{\lambda\,B} \,(A+B)\,e^{-\lambda\,A+B)}\\
&=& \left(A + e^{\lambda\,A}\,B\,e^{-\lambda\,A} - e^{\lambda\,A}\,e^{\lambda\,B}\,(A+B)\,e^{-\lambda\,B}\,e^{-\lambda\,A}\right)\,e^{\lambda\, A}\,e^{\lambda\,B}\,e^{-\lambda\,(A+B)}
\\
&=&\left(A+\mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,A})\left(B-\mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,B})\,(A+B)\right)\right)\,f\end{array}\tag{3}$$

All the above is perfectly general. You need to specialise it to your truncated case. So use the universally convergent (and here truncated to two terms) series (2) to expand $A+\mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,A})\left(B-\mathrm{Ad}(e^{\lambda\,B})\,(A+B)\right)$ and truncate it for your special case and I think you should make some headway.

---

A pedantic peeve: although both orders for the name are quite common, the order that accurately reflects the historical precedence is "Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff" as each of the authors made their contributions in 1897/1898 (Campbell), 1905 (Baker) and 1906 (Hausdorff), respectively. Each was aware of their forerunners' work, but, as stated in Fascicule 16 Ch 1 of Bourbaki (1960), "each found the demonstrations of his forerunners unconvincing(!)". That statement always makes me giggle and gives some comfort that I'm not the only one with about a 5% comprehension rate in reading technical literature (I reckon I need to read a paper about 20 times on average to "get" it). An amusing fact is that *none* of these three actually worked out the series. Instead, they established the theorem that the series was convergent within some neigbourhood of $\mathbf{0}$ in the Lie algebra and comprises linear and Lie bracket operations only. The formula itself is due to Dynkin and was fully worked out in 1947!

Comment: thank you so much for answering! I'll do my best to study your answer, despite my small introductory-level knowledge of lie groups and algebras.

Comment: @quarkleptonboson I've added another step to Eq. (3) to help you out. Just think of all the operators as square $N\times N$ matrices and all the Lie brackets and multiplications then become concrete matrix multiplications. (2) is always a literal matrix power series, since the group of invertible linear transformations on $\mathfrak{g}$ is always a matrix group.