# A symmetric representation of the displacement operator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-optics

Say that an operator is given by
$$D(\alpha) = \exp(\alpha a^{\dagger} - \alpha^{*}a) = \sum_{n=0} ^ {\infty} (n!)^{-1}(\alpha a^{\dagger} - \alpha^{*}a)^n.$$

Define $\{(a^{\dagger})^m a^n\}$ as the average of the ${n+m \choose m} = {n+m \choose n}$ differently ordered terms.

For example, $$\{a^{\dagger}a^2\} = \frac{a^{\dagger}a^2 + a a^{\dagger} a + a^2 a^{\dagger}}{3}.$$

How do I express $D(\alpha)$ in a neat, symmetric form (where $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ are on equal footing)? *For example* $$D(\alpha) = \sum_{n, m=0} ^ \infty \frac{\alpha^n(-\alpha^*) ^{m}}{n!m!} \{(a^{\dagger})^n a^m\}.$$

I am not sure how to do a binomial expansion of the first equation. There are posts which explain how to do it, for example [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/172512/binomial-expansion-of-non-commutative-operators), but I am not sure how to use on of the answers to proceed.

Comment: You are probably talking about the analog of [Weyl ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner–Weyl_transform#Weyl_quantization_of_polynomials)   for creation and annihilation operators. There are powerful ways to do this, and I'd be shocked if  no quantum optics text had that, but a tour-de-force of combinatorics is *not* a pathway to that goal.

Comment: It is assumed you have [read up](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0304094).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to treat them on equal footing, IMO, is to split the displacement operator in the following way
$$D(\alpha) = \exp(\alpha a^{\dagger} - \alpha^* a) =
 \frac{e^{-|\alpha|^2/2}e^{\alpha a^{\dagger}}e^{-\alpha^* a}
+e^{|\alpha|^2/2}e^{-\alpha^* a}e^{\alpha a^{\dagger}}}{2}$$
where one uses Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula. Now you can expand in a power series and match terms with identical powers of $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ from the two contributions.