# General derivative of the exponential operator w.r.t. a parameter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, mathematical-physics, hamiltonian, differentiation

I am interested in the calculation of the general $N$th derivative w.r.t. a parameter $\lambda$ of a quantum mechanical exponential operator with the following structure:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm d^N}{\mathrm d \lambda^N} e^{-\beta \hat H(\lambda)}
\end{equation*}
In the case $n=1$ this reads as
\begin{equation*}
\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{n!}[\hat H(\lambda)]^{m}\frac{\mathrm d\hat H(\lambda)}{\mathrm d \lambda}[\hat H(\lambda)]^{n-m-1}
\end{equation*}
Is there a compact fashion to rearrange the expression above for the general $N$th derivative?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: Use repeatedly the identity for the 1st derivative
$$ \frac{d}{d\lambda}e^{t\hat{A}} ~=~ \int_0^t\!dt_1~ e^{(t-t_1)\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_1\hat{A}}~=~ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2)~ e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_1\hat{A}} , \qquad t~\in~\mathbb{R}_+ .\tag{1} $$
For a proof of eq. (1) see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/41671/2451). Then the 2nd derivative becomes
$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2}{d\lambda^2}e^{t\hat{A}} 
&~=~\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~dt_3~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2\!-\!t_3)~ e^{t_3\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_1\hat{A}} \cr
&~+~ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2)~ e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2\hat{A}}{d\lambda^2}e^{t_1\hat{A}} , \qquad t~\in~\mathbb{R}_+ ,\end{align}\tag{2} $$
the 3rd derivative becomes
$$\begin{align} \frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^3}{d\lambda^3}e^{t\hat{A}} 
&~=~\iiiint_{\mathbb{R}^4_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~dt_3~dt_4~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2\!-\!t_3\!-\!t_4)~ e^{t_4\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_3\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_1\hat{A}} \cr
&~+~\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~dt_3~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2\!-\!t_3)~ e^{t_3\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2\hat{A}}{d\lambda^2}e^{t_1\hat{A}} \cr
&~+~\iiint_{\mathbb{R}^3_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~dt_3~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2\!-\!t_3)~ e^{t_3\hat{A}}\frac{1}{2!}\frac{d^2\hat{A}}{d\lambda^2}e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{d\hat{A}}{d\lambda}e^{t_1\hat{A}} \cr
&~+~ \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2_+}\!dt_1~dt_2~\delta(t\!-\!t_1\!-\!t_2)~ e^{t_2\hat{A}}\frac{1}{3!}\frac{d^3\hat{A}}{d\lambda^3}e^{t_1\hat{A}} , \qquad t~\in~\mathbb{R}_+ ,\end{align}\tag{3} $$
and so forth. The $N$th derivative $$\frac{1}{N!}\frac{d^N}{d\lambda^N}e^{t\hat{A}}~=~\sum\stackrel{t_{n+1}}{\rule{1cm}{.5mm}}\fbox{$k_n$}\stackrel{t_n}{\rule{1cm}{.5mm}}\cdots \stackrel{t_3}{\rule{1cm}{.5mm}}\fbox{$k_2$}\stackrel{t_2}{\rule{1cm}{.5mm}}\fbox{$k_1$}\stackrel{t_1}{\rule{1cm}{.5mm}}\tag{N}$$ 
is a sum of possible Feynman diagrams with Schwinger propagators $$\stackrel{t_i}{\rule{1cm}{.5mm}}~=~e^{t_i\hat{A}}, \qquad t_i~\in~\mathbb{R}_+,\tag{P}$$ 
and 2-vertices $$\fbox{$k_i$}~=~\frac{1}{k_i!}\frac{d^{k_i}\hat{A}}{d\lambda^{k_i}}, \qquad k_i~\in~\mathbb{N}.\tag{V}$$ Each diagram in the sum has weight 1.

Comment: That's horrifying.

Comment: Indeed a computational nighmare. But there is beauty behind the madness.

Comment: The problem with that is that you need to get through the madness to get to the beauty.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Ha-ha.