# What is the derivative of general 3D rotation with respect to one angular component?

Tags: operators, group-theory, commutator, lie-algebra, rotation

For a general rotation $R(t_1, t_2, t_3)$ where the $t_i$'s are the components of the rotation vector in the axis-angle representation. Is there closed formula for the derivative of $dR/dt_i$?

I only find derivative with respect to the magnitude of the angle, but not to the components of $t_i$

$$
\frac {dR(\theta)}{d\theta}=L_\theta R(\theta) 
$$
where $\theta=norm([t_1, t_2, t_3])$ is the rotation angle, and $L_\theta$ is the generator

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20axis%E2%80%93angle,the%20rotation%20about%20the%20axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis%E2%80%93angle_representation#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20axis%E2%80%93angle,the%20rotation%20about%20the%20axis).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15742/2451

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not straightforward. You can use the CBH formulae
$$
e^{-A} e^{A+\delta A} = 1+ \int_0^1 e^{-sA}(\delta A) e^{sA} ds+ O[(\delta A)^2] 
$$
and
$$
e^{-sA}(\delta A) e^{sA}= \delta A- s[A, \delta A]+ \frac {s^2}{2}[[A,[A, \delta A]]+\ldots
$$
It's easier with Euler angles where (using the 2 dim spin representation for convenience) we have
\begin{align}
R&=&
\exp\{-i\phi\sigma_3/2\}\exp\{-i\theta\sigma_2/2\}\exp\{-i\psi\sigma_3/2\}, 
\nonumber\\
&=& \left(\matrix{ e^{-i\phi/2} &0\cr
                     0        & e^{i\phi/2}}\right)
 \left(\matrix{ \cos \theta/2  &-\sin\theta/2\cr
                        \sin\theta/2  &\cos\theta/2 }\right)
 \left(\matrix{ e^{-i\psi/2} &0\cr
                     0        & e^{i\psi/2}}\right),
\nonumber\\
&=& \left(\matrix{e^{-i(\phi+\psi)/2} \cos\theta/2& -e^{i(\psi-\phi)/2} \sin\theta/2\cr
                  e^{i(\phi-\psi)/2} \sin\theta/2&
    e^{+i(\psi+\phi)/2} \cos\theta/2}\right). \nonumber
\end{align}
You get
$$
 R^{-1}dR = -\frac i2 \sigma_i \,\Omega_{\rm L}^i,
$$
where
\begin{align}
 \Omega_{\rm L}^1 &=& \sin\psi\, d\theta -\sin\theta \cos\psi\, d\phi,\nonumber\\
\Omega_{\rm L}^2 &=& \cos\psi\, d\theta +\sin\theta \sin\psi\, d\phi,\nonumber\\
\Omega_{\rm L}^3 &=& d\psi +\cos\theta\, d\phi.\nonumber
\end{align}

This answer does not depened on spin-1/2. Its the same for the 3d rotation matrices with the same Euler parameterization.

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about the Euler angles too. It's much easier to get the derivative that way

Answer (score 2):

Given the [usual generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Lie_algebra) $J_i$ for $i=1,2,3$ of the group $SO(3)$, a rotation matrix $R \in SO(3)$ can be written as
$$
R = e^{ i \, t_k J_k} \qquad (R^{-1} = e^{ -i \, t_k J_k})
$$
where the repeated index $k$ is summed.
Therefore (the limit for small $a$ is understood and $T = t_k J_k $ is an Hermitean matrix),
$$
\frac{d}{d t_1}R = a^{-1} \big( e^{ i(t_k+a\delta_{k1}) J_k}-e^{ i t_k  J_k} \big) = a^{-1} \big( e^{i T + i a   J_1 }-e^{ i T} \big)
\\
= a^{-1} \big( e^{ i T + a i  J_1 }e^{ -i T} - 1 \big)R
$$
Now, could try to use the [BCH formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) but would still give an infinite series: the "naive" approach would give
$$
e^{ iT + ia   J_1 }e^{ -i T} \approx e^{i T + ia   J_1   - iT +[T + a   J_1,T]/2} = e^{   a  (i J_1  +  [  J_1,T]/2)} \approx 1+ a   (i J_1  +  [  J_1,T]/2) 
$$
$$
\frac{d}{d t_1}R =  i J_1  +  [J_1,T]/2 =  i J_1  + n_k [J_1,J_k ]/2 
$$
You can easily calculate the last commutator with the usual commutation relation $[J_a,J_b]= i \epsilon_{abc}J_c$. Similarly for $t_2$ or $t_3$.
However, this is **NOT correct**: many other commutators of order $a$ are missing in the truncated BCH formula used above!

Therefore, you may try the [derivative of the exponential map](https://%20https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map),
$$
\frac{d}{d t_1}R = \frac{d}{d t_1} e^{i T} = \int_0^1  e^{i (1-s) T}
i\frac{d}{d t_1}T e^{i s T}  ds= i \int_0^1  e^{i (1-s) T}
 J_1 e^{i s T} ds = 
\\
=i\int_0^1 J_1 ds+ i \int_0^1  e^{i (1-s) T}
 [J_1, e^{i s T}] ds \,
=i J_1 + i \int_0^1  e^{i (1-s) T}
 [J_1, e^{i s T}] ds \, .
$$
Again, we have found the correct first term $iJ_1$, but the second integral term is a series (the full series that you would find by using the full BCH formula).

Comment: So there is no closed form result? I can easily compute such derivative with finite difference, but I wonder if there is a formula to evaluate directly

Comment: There may be closed form, but you have to use other methods, see @mike stone nice answer. With this method you can find successive approximations easily.