# Help deriving integral representation of derivative of exponential map for Lie algebras/groups using specifically using Riemann sum

Tags: particle-physics, group-theory, lie-algebra

I'm trying to derive the following equation using a Riemann sum formulation only

$$\frac{d}{d t}e^{A(t)} = \int_0^1 ds \quad e^{sA(t)}(\frac{d A(t)}{dt})e^{(1-s)A(t)}$$

What I've done so far is make sure I understand how to take the derivative of $e^{A(t)}$ for matrix $A$ and continuous parameter $t$:

$$\frac{d}{dt}e^{A(t)} = \frac{d}{dt}(\lim_{N\to \infty} (1 + \frac{A}{N})^N) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \sum_k^{N}(1  +  \frac{A}{N})^{N-k}  \frac{1}{N}\frac{dA}{dt}  (1  +  \frac{A}{N})^{k-1}$$

Here's a [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_of_the_exponential_map#A_direct_formal_argument) that may be relevant.

Now, the formula above makes perfect sense; it's just a matter of accounting for the non-commutativity of $A$ and carrying out the derivative of the limit definition of the exponential correctly. I see how the limit and sum together are implicitly an integral, but I can't seem to figure out the substitution correctly. It's obvious that since we're taking the limit as $N$ goes to infinity that I need to divide $k$ into infinitesimal chunks, so define $s = k/N$. This would make the $1/N$ term in the derivative expression I have above become $\Delta s$ since $k$ is an integer and summing over it would make $\Delta k = 1$ for all $k$. From here, my trouble is in how to get the exponents in the exponential terms correct.

[Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xPySaUBHn2ksBI9CbO-PVO9zVxKnjLac/view?usp=sharing) some of my work. I'm not sure if this is correct or not.

Comment: Why must you pick Riemann sums and this expression of exponentials to be the method? There are many other possible proofs, and something might be easier to understand.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/796986/2451

Comment: Hi Giovanni Brown. Welcome to Phys.SE. Please don't repost a closed question in a new entry. Instead, you are supposed to edit the original question within the original entry.

Comment: @Qmechanic yes I did that by explicitly stating I'd like to derive this in a specific way, specifically a grounds up direct approach without any gamma functions or integral identities nor the adjoint operation

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent the Riemann sum is what is mentally the most understandable to me, then I can move on to other derivations that may be a bit less direct

Comment: Try the argument after Equation (7) in this: https://webhome.phy.duke.edu/~mehen/760/ProblemSets/BCH.pdf

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent thank you so much man!!

Comment: That is precisely what I was saying in the first comment. Trying to get you to widen your search so that a vastly easier argument is available.